# What is meant by positive root of $x^3-x^3-1$?

Tags: roots

I am a bit confused. I think there must be a mistake.

In a text I read:

> > The entropy is $2\ln p$, where $$p=\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{29+9\sqrt{31/3}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{29-9\sqrt{31/3}}{2}}+1\right)$$ is the positive root of $x^3-x^3-1$.

---

But $x^3-x^3-1=-1$... I think that must be a typo? From what is $p$ the positive root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no positive root, or any root at all, of $x^3-x^3-1=0$, since, as you noted, $x^3-x^3-1=-1$ for all $x$, and there is no $x$ that satisfies $-1=0$. This is definitely a typo.

---

The positive root of $$x^3-x^2-1=0$$

is exactly

$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{29+9\sqrt{31/3}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{29-9\sqrt{31/3}}{2}}+1\right)$$

so that is almost certainly the [intended polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-x%5E2-1%3D0).

Comment: Thanks. But why is it mentioned that this root is the positive one. Because there is only one and it is positive.

Comment: @Salamo It is the positive root. It is also the only root. Authors can be redundant sometimes.

Comment: Haha, okay. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: The equation has three roots, of which just one is positive (the other two being complex). Still, it would be more natural to describe this root as the *real* root. Perhaps the author had in mind the need for the argument of the logarithmic function to be positive, and wanted to emphasize that it was indeed so.